# Android strace command error: "PTRACE_SYSCALL doesn't work: Function not implemented"

Tags: android, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I need to use strace on a rooted Android Asus ZenFone 2E, Intel Atom, x86.
So, I get a working binary for strace and run it on other phone and it is working perfectly. But when I tried to run the same command on Asus ZenFone 2E, it did not work.
The command is:

```
strace -f -c -p 123
```

The resulted error is:

> PTRACE_SYSCALL doesn't work: Function not implemented

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with cherry trail tablet... probably due to x86 file system, the binary having been compiled for arm devices

Comment: ...led for arm devices